# The logic behind the Mock system

Tags: java, mockito, easymock, powermock

In the market, there are different Java mock framework, for example, Mockito and PowerMock. I mainly ask in this thread what the logic behind the Mock system is. If there is an actual class, and there is a mock class.

What mock systems do is to replace bytecodes of actual class with mock class. If we are going to mock method, we just need to replace actual class's method bytecodes, with mock methods. Is that the logic behind the mock system?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) is a great insight into the theory of mocking by [Martin Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler).

Comment: The article does not say how to develop own mock library?

Comment: No, but it answers your question quite nicely. @user84592

Comment: Actually I want to know how one could develop its own mock system?

Comment: Shall I creat another thread to mean how to develop one's own mock system?

Comment: @user84592 I'm afraid, there is no tutorial on that. The best way IMHO is to grab the sources of an existing framework like Mockito/PowerMock and dig in. If you grasp the concepts from teh article well, it should be feasible

Comment: @user84592 I guess a new, properly titled question would be indeed better suited for your requirements.

Comment: @user84592 The approach you described as "replace bytecodes of actual class with mock class" is used by the JMockit Mockups API, one of two mocking APIs available in the JMockit toolkit (which I develop). Other approaches exist. Which approach is better depends on your requirements, on what you want to achieve with the mocking API.